# Why is this representation of $C^*\!$-algebras irreducible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

I'm focused on the text "Invitation to $C^*\!$-algebras" by Arveson. In this notation $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{H})$ is the set of compact operators  on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Here is the relevant text:

[image]

**Question**: Why is $\alpha$ an irreducible representation? I can see it is representation. Maybe the result that the only closed ideals in $\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{H})$ are trivial is relevant here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Irreducible* means that $\alpha(\mathcal C(\mathcal H))'=\mathbb C\,I$. And the commutant of $\mathcal C(\mathcal H))$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! A representation $\pi: A \to B(\mathcal{H})$ is called irreducible if the only subspaces $\mathcal{K}$ of $\mathcal{H}$ with $\pi(A) \mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathcal{K}$ are trivial. Is there a way to use this definition?

Comment: Yes, prove that $K(H)$ (the compact operators; Arveson's notation is hardly used these days) has no notrivial invariant subspaces. Do it. And, even more useful and important for the future, prove that $\pi(A)$ having no invariant subspaces is equivalent to $\pi(A)'=\mathbb C$.

Comment: With the commutant $\pi(A)'$ you mean the set $\{xy-yx: x,y \in \pi(A)\}$? And can you give a hint to start proving that $K(H)$ has no nontrivial invariant subspaces?

Comment: @user745578 the communant $\pi(A)' = \{ x\in B(H) \mid xy = yx \text{ for all $y\in \pi(A)$ }\}$, ie the operators that commute with every element of $\pi(A)$.

Comment: Ah I think I know this as a centralizer! Thanks!

Comment: You are reading section 1.4. The commutant is defined in section 1.2.

Comment: @MartinArgerami And do you have a hint to prove that $K(H)$ has no nontrivial invariant subspaces?

Comment: Yes. Take any two elements $x,y\in H$, and construct $T\in K(H)$ with $Tx=y$.

Comment: Thanks! That works!

Comment: You are welcome. I would like to insist that f you are going to do anything operator-algebra related, it is way more impotant to understand commutants than invariant subspaces; and you should understand that (at least for C$^*$-algebras and operator systems) the commutant encodes the invariant subspaces.

Comment: @MartinArgerami A related question: consider the shift operator $S$ on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and the $C^*$-algebra $A$ generated by $S$. Would it be correct to say that the identity representation $A \to B(l^2)$ is irreducible because $A$ contains all compact operators and thus the commutant of $A$ is trivial as well?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ \ $